# python TypeError:Expects an xxx as argument

Tags: python

If I define a class A in "tools.py", then I import that file in another file and create an object a using class A, the result of printing type(a) will be like <class 'tools.A'>, is there any way to remove 'tool' and make it print <class 'A'>?

tool.py

```
class A:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
aa = A()
print(type(A()))
```

its will print <class '**main**.A'>

problem.py

```
from triton_test.tool import *
print(type(A()))
```

its will printf <class 'triton_test.tool.A'>

so how can i get a class that type is <class 'A'>?

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example

Comment: also how does Your body text relate to the question title?

Comment: In case the solution isn't clear from the duplicate: implement a custom `__repr__` method to return whatever exactly defined string you want!